# Reliably dealing with nans in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

What's the best and hopefully easiest way to write over NaNs, also noting different cases?

In this example `df`, I want to replace the NaNs in `Routed (Expected) Site` according to business logic:

```
   DBN     DBN - Exam Routed (Expected) Site
00000A  00000A - Scie                 A00000
750000  750000 - Scie                    NaN
840000  840000 - Scie                    NaN
```

I want

```
   DBN     DBN - Exam Routed (Expected) Site
00000A  00000A - Scie                 A00000
750000  750000 - Scie          75 (Hospital)
840000  840000 - Scie           84 (Charter)
```

I use this code which actually doesn't indicate which case the NaN was:

`df['Routed (Expected) Site'].fillna('Charter or Hospital',inplace=True)`

I also tried this which somehow overrode all the `Routed (Expected) Site`s with `None`:

```
def routed_site_exceptions(DBN, routed_site):
    DBN = str(DBN)
    if DBN.startswith("84") and not routed_site:
        return '84 (Charter)'
    if DBN.startswith('75') and not routed_site:
        return '75 (Hospital)'
df['Routed (Expected) Site'] = np.vectorize(routed_site_exceptions)(df['DBN'],
                                                                    df['Routed (Expected) Site'])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `fillna` and `map`

I make an assumption that I don't know all that your business logic will entail.  So I kept it fairly generalized.

```
def routed_site_exceptions(DBN):
    DBN = str(DBN)
    if DBN.startswith("84"):
        return '84 (Charter)'
    if DBN.startswith('75'):
        return '75 (Hospital)'

df.fillna({'Routed (Expected) Site': df.DBN.map(routed_site_exceptions)})

      DBN     DBN - Exam Routed (Expected) Site
0  00000A  00000A - Scie                 A00000
1  750000  750000 - Scie          75 (Hospital)
2  840000  840000 - Scie           84 (Charter)
```

Comment: Thanks, I used:
```
    def routed_site_exceptions(DBN):
        '''
        Replace routed site for exceptions including charter and D79 schools. Meant to only be used when no values
        for them existed in the first place
        :param DBN: string | <12X000>
        :return: string | status | <'84 (Charter)'>
        '''
        DBN = str(DBN)
        if DBN.startswith("84"):
            return '84 (Charter)'
        if DBN.startswith('75'):
            return '75 (Hospital)'
    df['Routed (Expected) Site'].fillna(df['DBN'].map(routed_site_exceptions), inplace=True)```

Answer (score 2):

As describe, you can do:

```
# get the new values
s = df.DBN.str[:2].map({'75': '75 (Hospital)',
                        '84': '84 (Charter)'})

# map to the data
df['Routed (Expected) Site'].fillna(s, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
      DBN     DBN - Exam Routed (Expected) Site
0  00000A  00000A - Scie                 A00000
1  750000  750000 - Scie          75 (Hospital)
2  840000  840000 - Scie           84 (Charter)
```